# What happens to your possessions and/or your body when you die in die2nite?

Tags: die2nite

When you die outside the town in die2nite, what happens to the things in your satchel and/or your body? Do they disappear or do the object remain on the block where you die? If not, do my possessions remain on the block on which I die (so that the remaining citizens can make use of them)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. If you die in the World beyond, your possessions do stay on the square where you were eaten. Your fellow citizens can then travel to the square and retrieve them.

If you die in your house, your possessions can also be retrieved (stolen) by other citizens, but your corpse is also left behind, and can wake up and kill everyone if it isn't... taken care of.

*Methods of 'taking care of' include, but are not limited to watering, dragging out and barbecuing.*